# How can I make the content area a different colour from the wrapper?

Tags: css, navigation, textarea

I'd like to do two things: the first of these is to centre a content area of 1200px width. I'd like the navigation menu to be this width as well. The second thing I'd like to do is change the colour of this content area to white; whilst allowing a background area (wrapper) around the edge of the content area to remain the same colour.

```
/* BACKGROUND */

body {
 background-color: #ECF0F1;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 }

*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

img {
 border:0;
 }

/* AREA */

#wrapper {
 margin:0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 width: 1200px;
 background:#339999;
 font-size:1.20em;
 }

/* HEADER */

#header {
 margin-top: 40px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 }

/* PAGE */

#content {  
 min-height:400px;
 padding:23px;
 text-align:justify;
 line-height:1.5;
 }
```

It would be great if you could- for me and other users looking to format a webpage in a similar manner- tell me how to set up this content area and navigation bar

Thank You!

Comment: You can see my website at http://www.dragonclub.co.uk

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: +1;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* add this to make it center */
    left: 0; /* to give position of fixed menu */
    right: 0; /* to give position of fixed menu */
}
#content {
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: #fff; /* to color white your content */
    padding: 23px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smaller sample (in pixels) of what you're looking for:

[D E M O](http://jsfiddle.net/JjgVj/5/)

Ofcourse you can change the width to 1200px as needed..

```
/* BACKGROUND */
html { height:100%; width:100%;}
body {
 background-color: #ECF0F1;
 height:100%; width:100%;
 }

*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

img {
 border:0;
 }

/* AREA */

#wrapper {
 margin:0 auto;
height:100%;
 width: 300px;
 border:3px solid #339999;
 font-size:1.20em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 }

/* HEADER */

#header {
background:#ff6600;
margin:0 auto;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    font:bold 16px/100px arial;
 }

/* PAGE */

#content {  
 height:calc(100% - 100px);
    margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    font:bold 16px/200px arial;
 background:white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to do so many things here. Update the following class in your CSS. This will give basic alignment.

```
#menu { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
  width: 1200px; 
  background-color: #E74C3C; 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0px auto;
 }
 #header
 {
  /* margin-top: 40px; */ 
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100%; 
 }
  #content { 
  min-height:400px; 
  padding:23px; 
  text-align:justify; 
  line-height:1.5; 
  background-color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: This is great, but after changing the detail from relative to fixed and adding left and right margins from guarav's answer, I have noticed that the red block remains at the bottom of the page too. How could I fix this?

Comment: so you want keep the footer always on bottom of screen?

Comment: No, it is staying at the bottom of the screen and I dont want it there